Is there enough food in the Ocean to support large populations of Octopus?
Last Question I asked about a species of sapient Octopus, but now they have evolved, we have them now, and they also... eat food.
These Intelligent Octopus are, for all intents and purposes, Giant Pacific Octopus, like same size, metabolism, the whole shebangalangalango. They dwell all over the world.


(Excuse my bad drawings I am still practicing)
What I am asking for help on, is if these Octopus could get enough food to support enough population for a civilization. Like could the North Atlantic Ocean sustainably support a population of 100,000 Giant Pacific Octopus?
Like these Octopus they start to hunt and live in groups of a couple dozen, they have their home base at their group den and they patrol their area for their daily meal of shrimp, crabs, scallops, abalones, cockles, snails, clams, lobsters, or fish. Is there enough food for them in the Atlantic to grow in numbers to some hundreds of thousands? Or would these groups of Octopus be limited to a few per group who have to be nomadic due to not having enough prey or overhunting all their prey?
Is there enough food in the ocean for the octopus civilization, or did humans have more access to food on land than these octopus would have in the ocean?
Edit: To clarify, these sapient octopus live only in the ocean, and can't inhabit land. Also, it should be noted that Octopus don't really get the 3d experience in oceans like fish do, they crawl on surfaces or swim real close to them, as an octopus in open water is very vulnerable. Also Also, Giant Pacific Octopus, which are the ones this sapient octopus species is based off of, only inhabit areas down to 2000 meters below sea level, using Floodmap, this area can be seen as the light pale blue areas:


This is a bit of an odd quesiton. The ocean is 2/3 of the planet's surface and you're trying to support only 100,000 octopi. There likely already are 100,000 octopi and the ocean can feed orders of magnitude more than that. But when you say they're "all over the world," do you mean in all the world's oceans? or on the surface, too? Once on the surface, they'd start farming.

Well even though the ocean is 2/3 of the planet's surface they cant use all of it. For one, food is no doubt less abundant at the bottom of those really deep sea floors, and two, animals usually have a range of altitude they are limited to, in this case Giant Pacific Octopus have been spotted only down to 2000m, while that seems like it should leave a good amount of space, it is shocking how little it actually is compared to the rest of the ocean:
https://www.floodmap.net/  (setting the water level to -2000 m will reveal what areas they can inhabit)

Land Animals definitely have more area to inhabit than things in the ocean for sure. (Also yes the octopus dont live on the land they are limited to the ocean)

Please [edit] your post with clarifications. Never depend on people reading comments. Right now it's not clear that our octopi have not left the oceans. Additionally, land animals can't ever have more area to inahbit than life in the ocean. Remember, the ocean covers 2/3 of the Earth's surface - and that's just looking at it from the perspective of only two dimensions. Oceans (and the life they bear) are vast.

Octopus don't really get the 3d experience in oceans, they usually remain crawling on surfaces, or sticking real close to the surface, as an octopus in the open water is asking to be eaten. Although in terms of ocean life in general yes they definitely have more area than land animals, I had meant specifically that octopus would have less area than and animals. I will edit the post for clarifications now :]

That was an excellent edit. Thank you! Please note that the purpose of pointing out the size of oceans is that the ecology of ocean food chains depends on the 3rd dimension much more than it does for land-based creatures. Humans rely on almost nothing in the air other than the pollinating influence of insects (which can't be understated!). Your octopi have a third dimension to draw from regularly and wouldn't ignore that third dimension in terms of aquaculture/harvesting.

Plenty of food
Let's look at dolphins.  (I know you asked about octupus, but there is method here.)  The population of common dolphins alone in the North Atlantic is estimated to be over 400,000 according to this.  This is just one of 40 known dolphin species, the smallest of which are about 50 kg when fully grown.
What do the dolphins feed on?  Fish and squid are the primary food for most of them.  There needs to be a significantly larger number of a prey species than a predator species for a sustainable food chain, which means that if there are over 20,000,000 kg of one species of dolphins out there eating fish and squid then there probably needs to be around 200,000,000 kg of fish and squid for them to eat.  Assume a pessimistic 75:25 split, that gives 50,000,000 kg of squid in that area.  An intelligent species of octopus would probably drive out practically all the squid from "their" hunting grounds, the same way that humans have driven to near extinction the predators we competed with (wolves, lions, tigers etc).  So, if the area can support 50,000,000 kg of squid/octopus then that translates to over 3 million octopus of 15 kg each (as per the species description).
Note that this extrapolated solely from the population of a single species of dolphins and ignoring all the other food chain interactions in that area.  In practice, it would support a vastly larger population given an octopus civilisation - the eight-limbed ones would drive out all competitors/threats, including the dolphins, and get access to most of the fish as well.  Add at least an order of magnitude or two to the pessimistic estimate above and assume a population of at least hundreds of millions in the North Atlantic alone.

Nomadic living or Cultivating is necessary.
If you consider the history of humans, we were hunter/gatherers once but also nomadic because of the seasons and probably also because of prey moving from one spot to the next. To counteract we invented domesticating animals and performing agriculture, which are ways to replenish food sources on the spot rather than ever searching new hunting grounds. Villages and cities grew and allowed up to 40,000 people (+80,000 in the vicinities) on one spot with (very) rich crops and advanced irrigation - known as the oldest human city of Uruk in Mesopotamia, about 3000 BC.
Considering any form of flock/herd/swarm/pack animals, they all change habitats and feeding/hunting grounds at some point of growing population. Except small ones, like insects -mosquitoes especially- or birds and bats in tropical regions which can stay at one spot in large numbers (habitat with very large area and very rich on food).
The ocean is vast for sure. But there are better and worse spots to live in. A coral reef near the surface probably has all the food the octopus love. But somewhere deeper, darker and colder the food supply diminishes.
The more octopus live in a fertile spot, the less natural resupplying can happen. Imagining 100,000 octopus on one (big) coral reef would surely deplete the food sources sooner or later, making longer hunting trips necessary until also this does not return enough food for everyone. Probably this will even make a kind of work sharing necessary along the way, like some go hunt, some stay with the offspring, some defend the "camp" etc.
Long story short: Nomadic behavior seems to be necessary at least after a while when hunting grounds are depleted too much to sustain the whole population of octopus. Unless they invent something to counter the depletion. Like "planting" clam fields, putting up fish and crab "cages", etc. which are fed and bred systematically.
Alternatively they might develop digesting other food sources like kelp for example. Or they invent something to enhance "shelf-live" of their killed prey (by salt maybe?).
Or their metabolism is just so energy efficient that they need far less calories than anticipated and thus the hunting grounds stay sustaining over a very long period of time even if not cultivated.
Alternatively the distances between smaller groups of octopus needs to be (far) larger than their daily "hunting radius". This way the groups do not scavenge on each others food sources (and we assume the area is fertile enough to sustain a group over long periods of time). But this also means not everyone can live on the same (large) coral reef but the majority (probably) has to find their own spot somewhere.
